# jQuery Merge Data Attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, merge, attr

I'm trying to concatenate two data attributes when I click a button, and I'm wondering how I can merge them into one instead of adding the string before the first one,

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <button class="first" data-first='{"id":"1"}'>Test</button>
    <button class="second" data-second='{"action":"0"}'>Test</button>
</div>
```

I want to merge the `data-first` with `data-second` when I click the button with the `.first`

**jQuery**

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.first', function() { 

    var old = $('.second').attr('data-object');

    var add = $(this).attr('data-object');

    $('.second').attr('data-object', add+old);

});
```

But this returns

```
data-second="{"id":"1"}{"action":"0"}"
```

And what I'm looking for is

```
data-second="{"action":"0","id":"1"}"
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.second').data('object', $.extend({}, add, old));
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

There is a convenient way to deal with `data-` attributes in jquery available: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CqrwF/

Comment: Thank you very much, but now it's `[object object]` when I look at the source

Comment: @Mitchell Layzell: 1. use `.data()` 2. Create a jsfiddle demo that demonstrates the issue